# Identação automática em tags no Sublime Text 3

Tags: plugin, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, indentação, inline

Estou enfrentando problemas ao copiar e colar códigos XML ou HTML provenientes de outras aplicações no Sublime Text 3.

O código HTML por exemplo, após um ctrl + v, fica nesse estilo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body><h1></h1></body></html>
```

Gostaria de saber se existe um atalho ou plugin para inserir uma quebra de linha após o ">" de cada tag e realizar a indentação necessária para o código HTML ficar dessa forma:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <title></title>
</head>
<body>
      <h1></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Obrigado.